# what is best alternative to popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

As per project requirement what I want to achieve is to open multiple Urls  say `http://example1.com/track` `http://example3.com/info` `http://example2.com/history` after clicking one buttons

Currently we are using js popup window code ie

```
window.open ("http://example1.com/track","track"); 
window.open ("http://example3.com/info","info"); 
window.open ("http://example2.com/history","history");
```

But browsers blocks these popup windows. 
Is there anyway I can show user all URLS without blocking?

PS. I tried `iframe` but one of the website does not open in iframe.

Comment: fortunately you cannot (well, you cannot in most browser). If it's a requirement for a backend solution, you may ask to user to disallow popup blocker for your domain.

Comment: Already tried :( But practically it doesn't work. Displayed big message to user to allow pop up with help but user get confuse and then call customer care for same information.

Comment: Well. Then simply force the user to make 3 different click. It's a UX problem (that depends by your app)

Answer (score 2):

popup windows are now a day dead for malware risks
Flash and popups severely limit the possible customer base

here Some Alternatives

- Use [LightBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) or similar library
- Open A new tab instead of new window
- z-index and invisible/visible layers are the way to go

Comment: third point working well with hidden div's  on page we just populate them by using z-index and a overlay layer but for external url like in your case 2nd option can work have a look http://jsfiddle.net/U8wCc/1/

Comment: As per your code you are still using `window.open` so it will block. May be there is missing code from `http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/css-pop.js` and `http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/styles.css`